# Android:html and javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I am making an app in which i have to use javascript in android .Can anyone tell me how to use javascript in android , i mean to say will it be used in java class or any other means.Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link for a few tips. http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/10/android-webview-javascript-and-css.html

It depends on your application whether you want to use pure JS code, or you would have to have a Java-JS bridge.

Answer (score 0):

This previous poster figured out how to call JS from his android app:

[Android Calling JavaScript functions in WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview)

Here's a post regarding calling your android app from your JS:

[How to call android application from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808127/how-to-call-android-application-from-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) and you can just develop JavaScript and not worry about Java. The PhoneGap framework will take care of the necessary JavaScript to Android Java bridging.