# Can I call .java file from .html file with a link in android?

Tags: android

Can I call .java file from .HTML file, with the help of link in android?

I am new to android application development. And I have not that much idea. So Please Help me.

Location of .java file is in src/my_package_name folder and location of .HTML file is in assets/www folder.

I am trying to do with this by anchor tag in html file, I have given **href="ContactUs.java"** to link. It is not working.

Emulator shows me error. That is **Application Error. The Requested file was not found. ContactUs.java(file:///android_asset/ContactUs.java)**.

I am not sure it is correct way or not.

So please Suggest me if there is any better way to do this?

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution to open an activity from html.

First your main activity containing your webview:

```
package com.test.jsitest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WVActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView m_wv = null;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wv);
        m_wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        m_wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        m_wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        m_wv.addJavascriptInterface(new ActivityLauncher(this), "Android");
    }
}
```

Then your Javascript Interface:

```
package com.test.jsitest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ActivityLauncher {
    private Context m_context;

    public ActivityLauncher(Context context) {
        m_context = context;
    }

    public void launchActivity() {
        m_context.startActivity(new Intent((Activity)m_context,
             Activity2.class)); // Here you replace by your activity (ContactUs)
    }
}
```

And finaly your html file:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:Android.launchActivity()">Link</a> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I tested it and it works under a level 8 API.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: I am getting errors on this two lines.                                                        import android.annotation.SuppressLint; @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")                        Multiple markers at this line
- The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type 
        SuppressLint
- SuppressLint cannot be resolved to a type                         please tell how I solve it

Comment: I am developing app in api 10. will it make any difference.

Comment: Thanks for your code. It is running properly on 2.2 and now I am trying to run it on 2.3.3. thanks once again. you gave me exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript

You can't do it via html but you can via javascript, using a JavaScript Interface.

Comment: actually I want to navigate from html to java file, and html page will pass some values to java file for further operation.

Comment: When you say "navigate to a java file" are you speaking about an Activity?

Comment: yes absolutely. is it possible to navigate from html page to an activity with some values passed by html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call java file at all.   Java file on android is most probably part of application  ( and thus activity ) -  usually you have to use some URL protocol,  and androis system will call suitable application for you
Here is more about it:
[How to call android application from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808127/how-to-call-android-application-from-javascript)

Comment: thank u for your valuable replay. But is it possible to navigate from html page to an activity with some values passed by html page.

Comment: I have to pass some values from html page to Activity. Is it possible.